# Error al instanciar ! Ayuda con ese error

Tags: java

Lo que quiero realizar es  tener un vector y en cada posicion del vector (celda) tener un cola (cola de tipo array)
El Error me da en la sentencia:
Vector [0].meter (111);

Pero me da el error de la imagen.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Santiago, en tu proxima pregunta incluye el codigo y no una imagen. Asi sera mas facil copiar el codigo y probarlo.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cuál es la solución a todos los errores NullPointerException presentes, pasados y futuros?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/42977/cu%c3%a1l-es-la-soluci%c3%b3n-a-todos-los-errores-nullpointerexception-presentes-pasados)

Comment: La pregunta ya esta respondida estimado, Saludos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema es que no has instanciado los objetos de tu array, son nulos.
Entonces estás intentando acceder al método de un nulo, de ahí el NPE.
Tendrías primero que instanciarlos. Algo así:

```
Cola[] vector = new Cola[a];
for(int x = 0; x < a; x++) {
    vector[x] = new Cola();
}
```

Ya después podrías hacer lo que quisieras

Comment: Gracias no sabia eso la verdad. A hora me funciono . Thank you!

Comment: De nada compañero  ;)